Enumerating the files on a directory in localized case insensitive alphabetical order
I am trying to enumerate the files on directory, all mp4 videos, and get their dimensions using FFMEG's ffprobe.
This Bash script is working fine
for filename in *.mp4; do
printf "$filename;"
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=";" ${filename}
done

The result is a CSV like this:
video7.mp4;320;200
video1.mp4;800;600
videoAlpha.mp4;1024;1024

But now I want to do it in localized, case-insensitive, alphabetical order. How can I do that?

Add | sort -f after done?

There are two problems: (1) case-insenstitivity (i.e. ä and Ä being treated equal), and (2) locality (i.e. how should ä be sorted relative to a?). For the former, gnu sort has the option --ignore-case ; you may have to install it on your Mac. For the latter, I think this is controlled by LC_COLLATE, but I believe that this deserves its own question. Perhaps you could describe there what exactly you expect from "localized" sort order..

I expect exactly what you said, a á ã à â ä a å all be sorted as a, including their uppercase variations and the same for other character variations
